# How to Query the APIGee Cache

Tags: apigee

My Question: How can i query/list the contents of the cache.

So i have creates one cache from Management API->Environment Configuration.
Then i created a api proxy with no target and attached populate cache policy to it. e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PopulateCache async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="populateBlacklistByIP">
    <DisplayName>populateBlacklistByIP</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <CacheKey>
      <Prefix>CLIENTIP-</Prefix>
      <KeyFragment ref='request.queryparam.myvar'/>
    </CacheKey>
    <CacheResource>mycache</CacheResource>
    <Scope>Global</Scope>
<!-- no expiry -->
    <ExpirySettings>
        <TimeoutInSec>432000</TimeoutInSec>
    </ExpirySettings>

    <Source>request.queryparam.myvar</Source>
</PopulateCache>
```

Now i invoke the operation and get 200 ok back. But no way to check if the value made to cache or not.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Got My Answer from digging through the documentation.

Ref: http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/persistence.

Read this from url above:

Cache versus Key/value map
The PopulateCache policy does not persist cache entries. Entries are in memory until the configured expiration time. You can look up the value only until it expires.

## One limitation is that you cannot find the list of keys that are currently in a cache.

When using KeyValueMap, the keys are persisted indefinitely. There are APIs available to retrieve the list of keys. There is no expiration time for the keys; you must explicitly delete them.